# Entity Framework ORDER BY issue

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, exception, sql-order-by

I'm attempting to build my first MVC 4 application using the entity framework. All I'm looking for is to create a drop down list with the value and text of each option set to the same value.

This works, right up until I throw in the `GroupBy()`.

Create.cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownList("CustomerName",(SelectList)ViewData["companies"]);
```

ticketController.cs

```
ViewBag.companies = new SelectList(oc_db.company.Where(c => c.status == "ACTIVE")
                                                 .OrderBy(c => c.name_1)
                                                  .GroupBy(c=>c.name_1)
                                   , "name_1", "name_1");
```

Here is the Error I'm receiving:

> DataBinding:
>   'System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata+Grouping`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[OpsTicketing.Models.company,
>   OpsTicketing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
>   does not contain a property with the name 'name_1'.

If I don't use the `GroupBy` the query works, albeit with duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GroupBy` doesn't give you an enumeration of the underlying type.  It gives you an enumeration of `IGrouping` objects with a `Key` field that gives you the key value for that group and an `IEnumerable` interface that lets you iterate the members of that group.

If all you want is a unique list of `name_1` values in order, just select that field and do a `Distinct` followed by an `OrderBy`:

```
ViewBag.companies = new SelectList(oc_db.company.Where(c => c.status == "ACTIVE")
                                                .Select(c=> new {c.name_1})
                                                .Distinct()
                                                .OrderBy(c => c.name_1)
                                   , "name_1", "name_1");
```

Note that you *could* do it without the `.Select()`, but you'd have to define "equality" for your `company` class, which is more trouble than it's worth for this exercise.  That's why the `Distinct` didn't work before - because you didn't define what makes two companies distinct.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Sorry for the delay,I got pulled onto other things at work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to resolve the query before performing the GroupBy, which you can do by calling `.ToList()`

Comment: I dropped ".ToList()" in just before the ".GroupBy()" and receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

How about using .Distinct()?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx

Should work if this is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the grouping just to make the list distinct?  If so, try:

```
.Where(c => c.status == "ACTIVE")
.OrderBy(c => c.name_1)
.Distinct()
```

Comment: ".Distinct()" at the end seems to cancel out the ".OrderBy()". If I do ".Distinct().OrderBy()", the list is sorted, but not distinct.