# DataBinding: 'System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding

In controller;

```
var getSubjectClassList = (SMSEntitiesNew.Subjects).GroupBy(p => p.SubjectName).ToList();
SelectList listA = new SelectList(getSubjectClassList, "SubjectName", "SubjectName");  
ViewBag.getSubjectClassList111111 = listA;
```

In Index.cshtml;

```
@Html.DropDownList("getSubjectClassList", ViewBag.getSubjectClassList111111 as SelectList, "Please select Subject", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

When running Application, I am getting the following error :-

> DataBinding:
>   'System.Data.Objects.ELinq.InitializerMetadata+Grouping`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting error on these lines:

```
var getSubjectClassList = (SMSEntitiesNew.Subjects).GroupBy(p => p.SubjectName).ToList();
SelectList listA = new SelectList(getSubjectClassList, "SubjectName", "SubjectName");
```

The [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx) method actually returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` with `Key` property that provides key values(s) for grouped members and host `IEnumerable` interface which lets you iterate through all members inside the group. It doesn't give you `IEnumerable<Subject>` which you want to convert as `SelectList` instance.

If you want to insert unique `SubjectName` list into `ViewBag` that later converts to `SelectList`, you can perform `Select` query with `Distinct` and `OrderBy` like this:

```
var getSubjectClassList = (SMSEntitiesNew.Subjects).Select(p => new { p.SubjectName })
                                                   .Distinct()
                                                   .OrderBy(p => p.SubjectName).ToList();
```

Similar issue:

[Entity Framework ORDER BY issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593426/entity-framework-order-by-issue/14593505)

Comment: If you're satisfied to someone's answer, you can click accept mark to mark your question solved. There's no obligation for doing this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Please mail me the steps.  The link  (stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), I am not getting the slution for marking accept. My mailid- sibinthomask@yahoo.com